# angularjs and soap webservice

Tags: angularjs, soap, soapui

I am trying to call soap webservice through angular js code but i am getting below exception while sending xml through xmlHttp.send method where xmlHttp is 
var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized).**

When i sent the same request through soap UI Client,i am getting the correct response.I am also setting the credentials to validate the xml request through angular code given below:-

```
*app.factory("soapService", ['$soap',function($soap){
    var base_url = "http://10.75.108.90:61001/SOAPRouterServlet/?javaBean=true";

      $soap.setCredentials("ORWFMT01","******");

    return {
        GetUsers: function(){
            return $soap.post(base_url,"enterNotesForJob",{"destination": "AT", "pck": "PCK&lt;01069JobManagement123Clientuserid2001071912345678BT-0000000001339","callerId":"sss","besUserId":"*******","channel":"ORSI","jobNo":"GBB02001","e2EData":""});
        }
    }
}]);*
```

I am following this link for referral  [angular soap example](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap)

Comment: Looks fine, wrong credentials?

Comment: Credentials are fine.I am using same credentials in soap UI Client and it is working fine there.But when i am trying to do it from angularjs,it is giving me above mentioned exception.

Comment: You know the credentials by `$soap` are HTTP-Auth kind? -> https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap/blob/master/soapclient.js#L181

Comment: I am passing the credentials as following:
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +SOAPClient._toBase64(SOAPClient.username + ":" + SOAPClient.password));
Please let me know if it creates some problem

Comment: No that looks fine. Is it the line i marked in my last comment?

Comment: yes it is the same line that you marked.What i need to do in that?

Comment: Nothin I guess, is your SOAP provider secruity based on HTTP-Auth?

Comment: Yes it is needed.

Comment: do u have any solution please?

Comment: You said if you fire a request thrue your SOAP test client, it does work. You could compare the requests header/body of your request and response.

Comment: I am mocking the exact xml in soapclient.js which i am trying to send through soap test client.So there won't be any difference between requests.If u can suggest something,that would help a lot.

Comment: Please give some information about your backend. Which technology is used and which SOAP class?

Comment: Actually we are using java in the form of xml (GAF is our internal framework).My main purpose is to call soap webservice and get a response in xml and store it.thats it.I can also call soap service through java but that is quite difficult to do it from our internal framework.So i am trying to do it through angular

Comment: Have you tried to enable CORS? `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

Comment: No.Please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Well, iam not that familar with Java application you could take a look over here: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/

Comment: Important is that you also add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to send HTTP-Auth credentials.

Comment: can u share some reference link which shows adding of Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to send HTTP-Auth credentials in angularjs

Comment: Still done: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/